# how DateTime and TimeZoneInfo classes handles the daylight saving?

Tags: c#, .net, timezone, dst

I am trying to understand how .net does handle daylight saving. When I invoke `IsDaylightSavingTime` method and pass the date instance it returns true for today's date. If I invoke DateTime's `IsDaylightSavingTime` method on same date instace, it returns me false.

Why do I get different result for the same date instance?

```
public static void Main()
{
    var zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
    
    var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var pacificNow = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcNow, zone);
    
    Console.WriteLine(zone.IsDaylightSavingTime(pacificNow)); // Prints True
    Console.WriteLine(pacificNow.IsDaylightSavingTime()); // Prints False
}
```

here is the [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dfMeK8) for fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

The first line prints `True` because it is printing whether it is in daylight saving time in Pacific Time. Pacific Time changes to Standard Time on November 1 2020, and today is September 21, so it is daylight saving right now.

The second line prints `False` because it is not daylight saving in whatever timezone that your computer is in. This is because for `DateTime`s with a kind of `Local` or `Unspecified`, [`DateTime.IsDaylightSavingTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.isdaylightsavingtime?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) uses your computer's system timezone to determine its result:

> This method determines whether the current DateTime value falls within the daylight saving time range of the local time zone, which is returned by the [`TimeZoneInfo.Local`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.local?view=netcore-3.1) property.

[`TimeZoneInfo.Local`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.local?view=netcore-3.1):

> The local time zone is the time zone on the computer where the code is executing.

The timezone isn't actually part of a `DateTime`, so `pacificNow.IsDaylightSavingTime()` has no idea that you want it to use Pacific Time.